# cannot assign return value from fetch_assoc()

Tags: php

I write the php

```
$query = "SELECT privilege , no, userName FROM  $tableName WHERE userName =   

'$inputAccount' and password = '$inputPassword'";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if($result){
       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s %s %s\n", $row["privilege"], $row["no"], $row["userName"]);
    }
}
```

the result is `user 2 test`

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["privilege"]=$row["privilege"];
$_SESSION["no"]=$row["no"];
$_SESSION["userName"]=$row["userName"]

echo $_SESSION["privilege"] ;
echo $_SESSION["no"];
echo $_SESSION["userName"];
```

but the result comes to none things and I have fix it for a long time and cannot find why?

Thx in advance.

Comment: dose printf prints any thing?

Comment: Your application is likely wide open to SQL injections.  Use prepared queries.

Comment: are these codes are on different files????

Comment: They are in the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code, the problem was that you are not storing your sql output in variables and accessing the result outside of while loop.

```
session_start();
$query = "SELECT privilege , no, userName FROM  $tableName WHERE userName =   

'$inputAccount' and password = '$inputPassword'";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if($result){
       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //printf ("%s %s %s\n", $row["privilege"], $row["no"], $row["userName"]);
       $pr = $row["privilege"];
       $no = $row["no"];
       $name = $row["userName"];
    }
}

$_SESSION["privilege"]=$pr;
$_SESSION["no"]=$no;
$_SESSION["userName"]=$name

echo $_SESSION["privilege"] ;
echo $_SESSION["no"];
echo $_SESSION["userName"];
```

Comment: Thx, I forget the rule of the php varible scope.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're assigning values to `$_SESSION` *after* your `while` loop, `$row` will be `false` at that stage.

Comment: @Akam No they won't. How else would the loop exit?